# Schemas with nested objects GraphQL in typescript with decorators

Tags: typescript, mongodb, graphql, nestjs, schema

How to write schema in typescript of object with nested objects like this:

```
{
   "firstname": "Jhon",
   "lastname": "Doe",
   "adress": {
      "street": "Park Avenue",
      "city": "New York",
      "zipcode": "97000"
   },
   "active": true
}
```

I want to use some like this:

```
@Schema({ timestamps: true })
@ObjectType()
export class User {
  @Field(() => String)
  _id: MongooseSchema.Types.ObjectId;

  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  @Field(() => String, { description: 'First Name' })
  firstname: string;

  @Prop({ type: String, required: true })
  @Field(() => String, { description: 'Last Name' })
  lastname: string;

  // Adress object here

  @Prop({ type: Boolean, default: true })
  @Field(() => Boolean, { description: 'User status' })
  active: boolean;

}

export const UserSchema = SchemaFactory.createForClass(User);
```

I tried tu put some thing like this:

```
@Schema({ _id: false })
@ObjectType()
export class Adress {
  @Prop({ type: String })
  @Field(() => String, { nullable: true, description: 'Street' })
  street?: string;

  @Prop({ type: String })
  @Field(() => String, { nullable: true, description: 'City' })
  city?: string;

  @Prop({ type: String })
  @Field(() => String, { nullable: true, description: 'Zip Code' })
  zipcode?: string;
}
```

just here:

```
  // Adress object here
  @Prop({ type: Adress })
  @Field(() => Adress, { description: 'User Address' })
  adores: Adress;
```

But I get: **Error: Schema must contain uniquely named types but contains multiple types named "Adress".**

What is wrong? How can I create the nested object address?

Comment: Types can't be nested. One type can refer to another. The `adress` field needs to be of type `Address`

Comment: Thank you so much, maybe a code sample are more helpfully, sorry I am new in this